# parse complex logic expression and do the search, in php

Tags: php, parsing, search, logic

I'm working with a goods selling website that each product in the database (MySQL) belongs to several categories. I use a many-to-many table mapping to store the product-category relationship.

```
ProductID CategoryID
1          1001
1          1002
1          1003
2          1001
2          1003
2          1005
```

I think this approach is quite straight forward for general product search according to categories.

However, The internal user will search products by category in complex logic expression. 
e.g.:

input "(1001+1002)|1005" to find the products that belongs to category (1001 AND 1002) OR (1005).
input "(1001+1002)|(1003+1004)" to find products belong to category (1001 AND 1002) OR (1003 AND 1004).

Since the query is dynamic, I think it's not good to translate it to SQL directly. My approach is to retrieve the ProductIDs and CategoryIDs that appears in the query (for example "(1001+1002|1005)"):

```
SELECT ProductID, CategoryID FROM ProCatMap WHERE CategoryID IN (1001, 1002, 1005)
```

then do the final filtering in PHP.

After I select the ProductID-CategoryID records, I combine them into an array in the following format:
$Relation[$ProductID] = array(CategoryID1, CategoryID2 .....); so for the data listed above, the array will be

```
$Relation[1] = array(1001,1002, 1003);
$Relation[2] = array(1001, 1003, 1005);
```

My question is, how should I code to parse the dynamic logic query and do the filtering on the array.

The query only consists of AND(+) and OR(|) operators and brackets, and the brackets are always balanced. (e.g. each open bracket must has a close bracket in the query).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly - you should reconsider the approach and figure out a way for the database to do this sort of filtering for you.  It is what RDBMs are designed for.  Doing something like this in PHP (or any generic programming language) will be reinventing the wheel and most likely quite error prone.

You seem to already have the parsing logic down (+ and AND) will yield an intersection (| and OR) will yield a union.  Go with that.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. It's totally fine to do the filtering in  SQL. What I'm concerning is how to "translate" the input query into SQL or  a series of PHP conditions so that I can do the filtering in SQL or PHP. I tried with RegExp but it just can't do something recursively.